# Evento scroll no funciona en Firefox para Android

Tags: javascript, css, web, scroll, firefox

Tengo una página con un menú con el efecto estilo `sticky`, pero tuve que hacerlo mediante JavaScript y posicionamiento `fixed`, ya que el menú estaba dentro de un contenedor y no me funcionaba el usar la propiedad `sticky` de CSS.

La cosa es que en mi código JavaScript, cuando el valor de `scrolltop` es diferente a cero se activa un evento y se agrega una clase CSS al menú, para que pase a estar fijo en pantalla y cambie de color.  Esto me funcionó perfectamente en Chrome y Firefox para escritorio.

Pero en Firefox para teléfonos Android no me funciona, el efecto se activa pero no me quita la clase, nuevamente cuando vuelvo a la posición inicial.

En el inspector de elementos me aparece este mensaje:

> This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may
> not work well with asynchronous panning; see
> https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects
> for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and
> features!

Intenté investigar por mi cuenta, pero no entendí mucho a que se refieren, si me pueden explicar a qué se refiere el mensaje y por qué me ocurre esto me ayudaría mucho.

Incluso la página web la pueden revisar si desean, es [esta](https://alquimify.com/)

Dejo acá el código JavaScript, es bastante corto y fácil de entender:

```
let header = document.getElementById("header");
let inicio  = document.getElementById("inicio");

let altoHeader = header.offsetHeight;

function activarPegajoso(){

    let bajada = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    if(bajada !=0){

        header.classList.add("cambio");
        inicio.style.marginTop = altoHeader+"px";

    }else{

        header.classList.remove("cambio");
        inicio.style.marginTop = "0px";
    }

}

    window.addEventListener("scroll", activarPegajoso);
```